# Outlook addin custom button adding in drop down 

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-2010

Hi i am trying to add **custom button** in drop down in Outlook ....

like as shown in image ..black box is added as custom button [image]

some help how i can customize ribbon to get this ..

thanks 
nikhil

Comment: Is this for Office 2007 or 2010?

Comment: sorry i did not mention that..it is for office 2010.

Comment: i am working in visual studio .. with visual c++  i got reference code for VB here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909466.aspx but i am not able to work out for visual c++.

Answer (score 2):

thanks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforaMailItem

i have solved above issue after adding xml from above link in my VC++ code ribbon xml.